# Call MainActivityFragment from AppCompatActivity

Tags: android-fragments

How do I call MainActivityFragment from AppCompatActivity in Android? (I am new to Android.)

#### Code

main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Create new fragment and transaction

        }
}
```

Fragment

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    ArrayAdapter mforecastadapter;
    ListView list_view;

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View rootview= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

      String Items[] = {"Sandeep", "Santhosh", "Sangeetha", "Basil", "bibhas", "sumanth", "praveen"};
      List<String> weekforecast=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Items));

      mforecastadapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.fragment_main,R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,Items);
      list_view = (ListView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.listView);
      list_view.setAdapter(mforecastadapter);


      return rootview;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't really know what you mean by "call", but if you want to instantiate a fragment in an Activity, write this in your Activity:

```
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    YourFragment frag = new YourFragment ();
    ft.replace(R.id.container_for_fragment, frag);
    ft.commit();
```

Notice R.id.container_for_fragment is your xml attribute for containing the fragment instance. it can be `<fragment>`, `<FrameLayout>`.

This is the most basic way to do that. You can find some more examples on SO, how to use fragments BackStack, etc.

You can also use add() instead of replace() in FragmentTransaction, depends on your need.

I hope it helps you.